# how can I change toolbar searchView drop down menu theme to be light in android app

Tags: android, themes, searchview, dropdown, light

i have developed an android app with search view on action bar 
but the suggestion drop down menu items are dark.
is there a way i can turn the drop down menu to light ?

this is my style.xml file

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>

    <!--<item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.ListView.DropDown</item>-->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.PopupMenu</item>
    <!--<item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@android:style/Theme.Light</item>-->
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<style name="AppTheme.ButtonBase" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
    <item name="android:paddingTop">12dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">12dip</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16.9sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ButtonPrimary" parent="AppTheme.ButtonBase">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/buttonPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/textLight</item>
</style>


<style name="MineCustomTabText" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ButtonSecondary" parent="AppTheme.ButtonBase">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/textLight</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just comment out your style code. for below attribute in your code.

`android:dropDownListViewStyle`

Now build and run your app again.

It will help you.

Comment: i did but nothing happened

Comment: Can you share snapshot of your app screen to me ?. you can send me on my skype id: akshaydonga

Comment: I fixed it by changing the autoCompleteTextViewStyle color :)